# Django returning FieldDoesNotExist error on server but passes fine in shell

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-2.6

I'm trying to get a ValuesQuerySet with a specific set of FK fields that span relationships between multiple tables. When I run this query in the django shell, there's not even a hiccup. But when running it on the development server, Django returns FieldDoesNotExist errors on some, but not all, of these FK fields.

Here are the pertinent models (I'm using the standard Django User model):

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)
    headline = models.TextField(null=True)
    connections = models.ManyToManyField('self',through="Connection",symmetrical=False,related_name="connections+")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15,default="active")

class Position(models.Model):

    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity,related_name="positions")
    person = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="positions")
    careers = models.ManyToManyField("Career",related_name="positions")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=450,null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    current = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=450,null=True)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=450,null=True)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=450,null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15,default="active")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

class Entity(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=450)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15,default="active")

class Picture(models.Model):

    person = models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name="pictures")
    pic = models.ImageField(max_length=450,upload_to=_get_picture_path)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=45,null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    license = models.TextField(null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15,default="active")
```

In one view, I run two slightly different queries to get a slice of users with information pulled from these connected tables (one is restricted to an array of user ids, `user_ids`):

```
some_people = User.objects.values('id','profile__headline','profile__first_name','profile__last_name','profile__pictures__pic','positions__entity__id','positions__entity__name').filter(id__in=user_ids).annotate(no_of_pos=Count('positions__id')).order_by('-no_of_pos')

all_people = User.objects.select_related('positions','profile').values('id','profile__headline','profile__first_name','profile__last_name','profile__pictures__pic','positions__entity__id','positions__entity__name').annotate(no_of_pos=Count('positions__id')).order_by('-no_of_pos')
```

These functions are almost identical, one is restricted to a predefined set of users (identified by id) and the other is not. I know that these results will return duplicates of some information, but I take care of that in a later step when I assemble this information into slightly different dictionaries for templates

If I run these queries in the shell, there are no problems. Queries don't take any time and all fields are evaluated properly. However, the development server returns this error:

```
User has no field named 'headline'
```

It returns similar errors as long as "profile_*headline", "profile*_pictures_*pic", "positions*_entity_*name" are included. This error doesn't make any sense to me. Those fields do exist, but not on the User object -- and they are never called on the user object. In addition, why just these fields? "profile*_last_name", "profile__first_name" and "positions_*entity*_id" should all fall into the same bin, it seems like to me.

Please help me resolve this -- any ideas?

I'm running Django 1.4.2 with Python 2.6 on a Mac OS X.

Comment: What is your database backend?

Comment: postgresql with `postgresql_psycopg2` backend. Just drop and recreated database and haven't modified the models. I'm also using `South` but I'm not sure that should make a difference.

Comment: `South` might affect stuff. I'm trying to think of what is different between the `shell` environment and the `dev server` environment.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the model definition that you have on your development server does not match the physical database schema that you have. Probably because you have added new fields and have not migrated them yet.

To check, run `./manage.py migrate --list`. If that's the case, a migration on the development server should solve the problem.

Comment: Both shell and the dev server are running locally and using the same database. I've run through all the migrations as well again after recreating the database and that doesn't change anything.

Comment: In psql shell or pgadmin, do you actually see the `headline` field in the table definition?